# dynamically changing divisions in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a code that on click on different links the specific divisions changes respectively.

first file is:
index.html

```
<div class="wrapper">       
    <div class="grid3 first">
        <ul class="categories">
            <li><a id="Engineering">Aerospace</a></li>
            <li><a id="Productive">Automotive</a></li>
            <li><a href="Chemicals">Chemicals</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <section id="neeraj_content">    
        <div class="grid19" id="Engineering" >
            <h2>Grow service revenue with world-class<br/>
            lifecycle service and support.</h2>
            <p>some displaying content here that appears in the division grid19 </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

in this index file i have a js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#neeraj_menu ul li a').click(function(){
            $('#neeraj_content').load('division.html #' + $(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

now I have made another html file named division.html in which the other contents that have to appear in the division grid19 have to appear on that specific position

```
        <div class="grid19" id="Engineering" >
            <h2>Grow service revenue with world-class<br/>
            lifecycle service and support.</h2>
            <p>some displaying content here that appears in the division grid19 </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

        <div class="grid19" id="Productive" >
            <h2>Grow service revenue with world-class<br/>
            lifecycle service and support.</h2>
            <p>some displaying content here that appears in the division grid19 </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

        <div class="grid19" id="Chemicals" >
            <h2>Grow service revenue with world-class<br/>
            lifecycle service and support.</h2>
            <p>some displaying content here that appears in the division grid19 </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Now on click of productive or chemicals the content of the division has to change. I am having problem in changing it. It actually accesses the specific id in the division.html file. Its not working. Have issues in it. I can't get where the error is. 
Also it does change because i had tired it earlier and it worked, now i have forgotten how it did the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing:

```
$('#neeraj_menu ul li a').click(function(){
```

but in the html code that you provide the id neeraj does not appear